# PHP - Use pdo fetch multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have below query:

```
//Get the data
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM softbox_bookings_data t1
LEFT JOIN softbox_bookings t2 ON t1.booking_id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id=:id
GROUP BY t1.model
ORDER BY t2.time ASC");
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $_GET["id"]);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Now I want to be able to use above query multiple times.

First I want to just echo out a variable:

```
echo $data["name"];  //Returns nothing
```

Then further down the page, I want to loop the data:

```
foreach($data as $row){
    echo $row["name"]; //Successfully echoes out the name from the database.
}
```

How come I can't use the `echo $data["name"]` variable and the `foreach()` statement to run through the data?

Comment: `$data` is two-dimensional array: `echo $data[0]["name"];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on [error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) and **always** use [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) instead of [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) when checking variable values. The latter will only print strings, but `data` is a two-dimensional array. Just check the `var_dump` output.

BTW: Of course `echo` "returns" nothing, its return type is void.